# using displaytag how to export only selected columns?

Tags: struts2, displaytag

I am using hibernate, struts2, jsp and display tag library fo a basic web app. I am new in display tag library. I am trying to display user data, with edit and delete columns. while exporting the display table, i want to exclude these edit and delete columns. How can i do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place `media="html"` in edit and delete column so it doesn't export those columns

code changed in the above snippet::

```
display:column title="Edit"   media="html"
display:column title="Delete" media="html"
```